# STUN/TURN server configuration for Django channels with WebRTC

Tags: django, webrtc, django-channels, stun, turn

I developed using django channels to implement video chat and message chat.(I was referring to a YouTuber's course.)

When I first completed the development, I noticed that webrtc works only in the local network, and I found out that a stun/turn server was needed.

So, I created a separate EC2 and built the stun/turn server and set this to the RTCPeerconnection in the web server.

Stun/turn server test in Trickle ICE is good.

But My video call still works only within the local network. And even within the same network, the connection was very slow.

---

Server overall configuration.(Webserver with SSL application loadbalancer)
[image: Webserver with SSL application loadbalancer]

---

Coturn config

```
# /etc/default/coturn
TURNSERVER_ENABLED=1

# /etc/turnserver.conf
# STUN server port is 3478 for UDP and TCP, and 5349 for TLS.
# Allow connection on the UDP port 3478
listening-port=3478
# and 5349 for TLS (secure)
tls-listening-port=5349

# Require authentication
fingerprint
lt-cred-mech

server-name=mysite.com
realm=mysite.com

# Important:
# Create a test user if you want
# You can remove this user after testing
user=myuser:userpassword

total-quota=100
stale-nonce=600

# Path to the SSL certificate and private key. In this example we will use
# the letsencrypt generated certificate files.
cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/stun.mysite.com/cert.pem
pkey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/stun.mysite.com/privkey.pem

# Specify the allowed OpenSSL cipher list for TLS/DTLS connections
cipher-list="~~~~~-SHA512:~~~~~SHA512:~~~~~-SHA384:~~~~~SHA384:~~~-AES256-SHA384"

# Specify the process user and group
proc-user=turnserver
proc-group=turnserver
```

main.js in Web Server

```js
let mapPeers = {};

let usernameInput = document.querySelector('#username');
let btnJoin = document.querySelector('#btn-join');

let username;
let webSocket;

const iceConfiguration = {
    iceServers: [
        { urls:'stun:stun.mysite.com' },
        {
            username: 'myuser',
            credential: 'userpassword',
            urls: 'turn:turn.mysite.com'
        },
    ]
}

function webSocketOnMessage(event) {
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(event.data);
    let peerUsername = parsedData['peer'];
    let action = parsedData['action'];

    if (username === peerUsername){
        return;
    }

    let receiver_channel_name = parsedData['message']['receiver_channel_name'];

    if (action === 'new-peer'){
        createOfferer(peerUsername, receiver_channel_name);

        return;
    }

    if (action === 'new-offer'){
        let offer = parsedData['message']['sdp']

        createAnswerer(offer, peerUsername, receiver_channel_name);

        return;
    }

    if (action === 'new-answer'){
        let answer = parsedData['message']['sdp'];

        let peer = mapPeers[peerUsername][0];

        peer.setRemoteDescription(answer);

        return;
    }

    // console.log('message : ', message)
}

btnJoin.addEventListener('click', () => {
    username = usernameInput.value;

    console.log('username : ', username);

    if (username === ''){
        return;
    }
    usernameInput.value = '';
    usernameInput.disabled = true;
    usernameInput.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    btnJoin.disabled = true;
    btnJoin.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    let labelUsername = document.querySelector('#label-username');
    labelUsername.innerHTML = username;

    let loc = window.location;
    let wsStart = 'ws://';

    if (loc.protocol === 'https:'){
        wsStart = 'wss://';
    }

    let endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + loc.pathname + 'ws/';

    console.log(loc.host)
    console.log(loc.pathname)
    console.log('endpoint: ', endpoint);

    webSocket = new WebSocket(endpoint);
    console.log('--------', webSocket)

    webSocket.addEventListener('open', (e) => {
        console.log('Connection opened!');

        sendSignal('new-peer', {});

    });
    webSocket.addEventListener('message', webSocketOnMessage);
    webSocket.addEventListener('close', (e) => {
        console.log('Connection closed!', e)
    });
})


// Media
let localStream = new MediaStream();

const constraints = {
    'video': true,
    'audio': true
}

const localVideo = document.querySelector('#local-video');

const btnToggleAudio = document.querySelector('#btn-toggle-audio');
const btnToggleVideo = document.querySelector('#btn-toggle-video');

let userMedia = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(stream => {
        localStream = stream;
        localVideo.srcObject = localStream;
        localVideo.muted = true;

        let audioTracks = stream.getAudioTracks();
        let videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();

        audioTracks[0].enabled = true;
        videoTracks[0].enabled = true;

        btnToggleAudio.addEventListener('click', () => {
            audioTracks[0].enabled = !audioTracks[0].enabled;
            if (audioTracks[0].enabled){
                btnToggleAudio.innerHTML = 'Audio mute'
                return;
            }
            btnToggleAudio.innerHTML = 'Audio unmute'
        });

        btnToggleVideo.addEventListener('click', () => {
            videoTracks[0].enabled = !videoTracks[0].enabled;
            if (videoTracks[0].enabled){
                btnToggleVideo.innerHTML = 'Video off'
                return;
            }
            btnToggleVideo.innerHTML = 'Video on'
        });

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error accessing media devices', error);
    });


// Message
let btnSendMsg = document.querySelector('#btn-send-msd');
let messageList = document.querySelector('#message-list');
let messageInput = document.querySelector('#msg');

btnSendMsg.addEventListener('click', sendMsgOnclick);

function sendMsgOnclick() {
    let message = messageInput.value;
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Me: ' + message));
    messageList.appendChild(li);

    let dataChannels = getDataChannels();

    message = username + ': ' + message;

    console.log("---------console.log(dataChannels)----------")
    console.log(dataChannels)

    for (index in dataChannels){

        console.log("---------console.log(index)----------")
        console.log(index)

        dataChannels[index].send(message);
    }

    messageInput.value = '';

}

function sendSignal(action, message){
    let jsonStr = JSON.stringify({
        'peer': username,
        'action': action,
        "message": message,
    });
    webSocket.send(jsonStr);
}

function createOfferer(peerUsername, receiver_channel_name) {
    let peer = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration);
    console.log('=================================')
    console.log(peer)
    console.log('=================================')

    addLocalTracks(peer);

    let dc = peer.createDataChannel('channel');
    dc.addEventListener('open', () => {
        console.log('connection opened!')
    })
    dc.addEventListener('message', dcOnMessage);

    let remoteVideo = createVideo(peerUsername);
    setOnTrack(peer, remoteVideo);

    mapPeers[peerUsername] = [peer, dc];

    peer.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', () => {
        let iceConnectionState = peer.iceConnectionState;

        if (iceConnectionState === 'failed' || iceConnectionState === 'disconnected' || iceConnectionState === 'closed'){
            delete mapPeers[peerUsername];

            if (iceConnectionState !== 'closed'){
                peer.close();
            }

            removeVideo(remoteVideo);
        }

    })

    peer.addEventListener('icecandidate', (event) => {
        if (event.candidate){
            console.log('new ice candidate', JSON.stringify(peer.localDescription))

            return;
        }

        sendSignal('new-offer', {
            'sdp': peer.localDescription,
            'receiver_channel_name': receiver_channel_name
        });

    });

    peer.createOffer()
        .then(o => peer.setLocalDescription(o))
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Local description set successfully!');
        });
}

function createAnswerer(offer, peerUsername, receiver_channel_name) {
    let peer = new RTCPeerConnection(iceConfiguration);

    console.log('=================================')
    console.log(peer)
    console.log('=================================')

    // let peer = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
    addLocalTracks(peer);

    let remoteVideo = createVideo(peerUsername);
    setOnTrack(peer, remoteVideo);

    peer.addEventListener('datachannel', e => {
        peer.dc = e.channel;

        peer.dc.addEventListener('open', () => {
            console.log('connection opened!')
        })
        peer.dc.addEventListener('message', dcOnMessage);

        mapPeers[peerUsername] = [peer, peer.dc];
    });

    peer.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', () => {
        let iceConnectionState = peer.iceConnectionState;

        if (iceConnectionState === 'failed' || iceConnectionState === 'disconnected' || iceConnectionState === 'closed'){
            delete mapPeers[peerUsername];

            if (iceConnectionState !== 'closed'){
                peer.close();
            }

            removeVideo(remoteVideo);
        }

    })

    peer.addEventListener('icecandidate', (event) => {
        if (event.candidate){
            console.log('new ice candidate', JSON.stringify(peer.localDescription))

            return;
        }

        sendSignal('new-answer', {
            'sdp': peer.localDescription,
            'receiver_channel_name': receiver_channel_name
        });

    });

    peer.setRemoteDescription(offer)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Remote description set successfully for %s.', peerUsername);

            return peer.createAnswer();
        })
        .then(a => {
            console.log('Answer created!')

            peer.setLocalDescription(a);
        })

    // peer.createOffer()
    //     .then(o => peer.setLocalDescription(o))
    //     .then(() => {
    //         console.log('Local description set successfully!');
    //     });
}

function addLocalTracks(peer) {
    localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
        peer.addTrack(track, localStream);

        return;
    });
}

function dcOnMessage(event) {
    let message = event.data;

    let li = document.createElement('li')
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    messageList.appendChild(li);
}

function createVideo(peerUsername) {
    let videoContainer = document.querySelector('#video-container');
    let remoteVideo = document.createElement('video');

    remoteVideo.id = peerUsername + '-video';
    remoteVideo.autoplay = true;
    remoteVideo.playsInline = true;

    let videoWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    videoContainer.appendChild(videoWrapper);
    videoWrapper.appendChild(remoteVideo);

    return remoteVideo;

}

function setOnTrack(peer, remoteVideo) {
    let remoteStream = new MediaStream();
    remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;

    peer.addEventListener('track', async (event) => {
        remoteStream.addTrack(event.track, remoteStream);
    });
}

function removeVideo(video) {
    let videoWrapper = video.parentNode;
    videoWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(videoWrapper);

}

function getDataChannels() {
    let dataChannels = []

    for (peerUsername in mapPeers){
        let dataChannel = mapPeers[peerUsername][1];

        dataChannels.push(dataChannel);

    }

    return dataChannels;

}
```

django channels code in webserver

```py
# Consumer.py
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        print('connect!!')
        self.room_group_name = 'test_room'

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        print(f"room_group_name : {self.room_group_name} and channel_name : {self.channel_name}")

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        print('disconnected!')

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        receive_dict = json.loads(text_data)

        print(f"receive_data : {receive_dict}")

        message = receive_dict['message']
        action = receive_dict['action']

        if (action == 'new-offer') or (action == 'new-answer'):
            receiver_channel_name = receive_dict['message']['receiver_channel_name']

            receive_dict['message']['receiver_channel_name'] = self.channel_name

            await self.channel_layer.send(
                receiver_channel_name,
                {
                    'type': 'send.sdp',
                    'receive_dict': receive_dict
                }
            )

            return

        receive_dict['message']['receiver_channel_name'] = self.channel_name

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'send.sdp',
                'receive_dict': receive_dict
            }
        )

    async def send_sdp(self, event):
        print('send_sdp!!')
        receive_dict = event['receive_dict']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(receive_dict))



# asgi.py
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Project.settings')
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import video_app.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                video_app.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
            )
        ),
})


#routing.py
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"^ws/$", consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]


# settings.py
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
        "default": {
            "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
            "CONFIG": {
                "hosts": [("myredis.cache.amazonaws.com", 6379)]
            },
        },
    }
```

What is my fault?